# How do I deep copy in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a situation similar to what you see below. The variable `id` is set to '03' before the first asynchronous callback is returned. Is there a way to deep copy, or "close" around the variable like you can with blocks in Objective-C? Is there a best practice?

```
var ids = ['01', '02', '03'];

for(var i=0, i < ids.length; i++){
  var id = ids[i];
  collection.find({id: ids} function () {
    console.log(id);
  });
}
```

The console output is:

```
03
03
03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use .forEach() instead of a for loop you get the closure for free:

```
var ids = ['01', '02', '03'];

ids.forEach(function (id) {
  collection.find({id: ids} function () {
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

Or if you don't have ES5-isms like .forEach() you can use a self-executing function to close over state. Here we'll just create an innerly-scoped `i` separate from the parent `i`:

```
var ids = ['01', '02', '03'];

for (var i=0; i < ids.length; i++) (function (i) {
    var id = ids[i];
    collection.find({id: ids} function () {
        console.log(id);
    });
})(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it.  One is to iterate with a a method that uses a closure as a callback.

```
ids.forEach(function (elem) {
    collection.find({id: ids} function () {
        console.log(elem);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a closure creates a private scope, which will do what you are expecting.

```
var ids = ['01', '02', '03'];

for(var i=0, i < ids.length; i++){
  var id = ids[i];
  (function(index){ 
      collection.find({id: ids}, function () {
          console.log(index);
      });
  })(id); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery. It's easy

var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);

That's all you have to do.